# Geopdf map not displaying coordinates in Adobe Acrobat Geospatial Location Tool.

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geopdf

I georeferenced a map using a data layer from ArcGis online as a base map. I transformed the now georeferenced map to the WGS 1984 World Mercator projected coordinate system. Lastly, I exported the map from ArcGIS as a PDF. I exported all data layers. However when I open in Adobe and use the Geospatial Location tool the lat and long bar remains blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you run the gdalinfo command & post the result here? example  -  `c:\>gdalinfo mygeospatial.pdf`  Also, did you toggle "Export Map Georeference Information" on the 'Export Map' dialogs' 'Advanced' tab when exporting as a pdf?

Comment: There are two common ways to georeference PDF. One is a proprietary system by TerraGo, the other an extension to PDF standard made by Adobe. Perhaps ArcGIS is using the TerroGo system. The GDAL driver info page gives some more information and new links http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html.

Comment: Adobe is using the Esri projection engine internally. There's a bug with EPSG::3857 because Adobe is using a very old copy of the library. Did you use "WGS 1984 Web Mercator" or "WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)"? If the latter, try using the former one. Also, what version of ArcGIS?

Comment: @cm1 this is the result of the gdalinfo:

Comment: @cm1 the result of gdal info is:Size is 2648, 1406
Coordinate System is:
'PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,'

Comment: AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,

Comment: AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-3.339584722840628,8.905559261850064)
Pixel Size = (0.007146559664603,-0.007123078664860)
Metadata:
  CREATION_DATE=D:20161108180751-08
  CREATOR=Esri ArcMap 10.2.2.3552

Comment: NEATLINE=POLYGON ((-3.339584722840627 -1.113194908926494,-3.339584722840627 8.905559261850064,15.58472871036621 8.905559261850064,15.58472871036621 -1.113194908926494,-3.339584722840627 -1.113194908926494))
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -3.3395847,   8.9055593) (  0d 0' 0.11"W,  0d 0' 0.29"N)
Lower Left  (  -3.3395847,  -1.1094893) (  0d 0' 0.11"W,  0d 0' 0.04"S)
Upper Right (  15.5845053,   8.9055593) (  0d 0' 0.50"E,  0d 0' 0.29"N)
Lower Right (  15.5845053,  -1.1094893) (  0d 0' 0.50"E,  0d 0' 0.04"S)
Center      (   6.1224603,   3.8980350) (  0d 0' 0.20"E,  0d 0' 0.13"N)

Comment: @mkennedy I'm using WGS 1984 Web Mercator and I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.